# How to self join data models many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of shops.
Each shop has a type (eg: Pharmacy, Shoes, Burgers, Clothing, etc)
Shops also have contacts, address, etc which are simple relationships, but the relationship to SELF, has me perplexed.

A shop, may be related to many other shops, and the data structure is as follows.
**shop**

```
id
name
shop_type_id
```

A linking table provides the relationship
**shop_link**

```
id
shop_id
related_shop_id
```

Where shop_id, and related_shop_id are both FKs to the shop table.

To model this, my shop model has the following entry to fetch related shops.

```
public function related_shop(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'shop_link', 'shop_id', 'related_shop_id');
}
```

To fetch the data, I try to access

```
Shop->related_shop()->get();
```

However, this only gives me the data from the linking table.
What I wish to retrieve, is the model for the related shop, with all the related data.
Eg:

> Shop
>
> - id: 1
> - name: My Shop
> - shop_type_id: 3
> - related_shop
>
>   - id: 6
>   - name: Bens Shoes
>   - shop_type_id: 2

How do I access the model for the related shops?
Eg: A list of all related shop names.

Comment: That should be working, what are the results of your query ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @matiaslauriti. It was working but my Resource in app/Http/Resources/Json/ShopResource.php was messed up.